# Laravel is generating random cookies and its hitting the server limit

Tags: laravel, cookies

My application uses Laravel 8 with Sanctum and it's hitting the long cookie error from nginx. When I checked the cookies, I could see many random cookies got created. How can I get rid of these randomly generated cookies? - delete or prevent this from generating ?

[image]